# Developed webRTC Web App, Need Help For Native Apps

Tags: android, ios, node.js, sockets, webrtc

I'm developing a webRTC project, the goal is to have 8 random people on the same channel, sharing video and audio, while having the possibility of being on different platforms (iOS, Android, PC, etc).

So far, so good, I finished developing the browser client and the server (using Socket.io and Node.js), and it is working fine.
The problem is I used a webRTC abstraction to code the browser instead of the apprtc libraries, and the library I used doesn't support native apps.

My question is, should I try to code a new library for mobile based on the abstraction library I used (around 6k lines of code), try to find a way to connect peers running on the browser abstraction library and the peers using an android/iOS abstraction library, or should I re-write all client side code with apprtc samples?

The goal here is to have everything working as fast as possible and have the possibility to optimize later on.

A few notes on my project:

->The interface will be really simple, all the user has to do is click a button, I will then check for video and send him to a queue in the server (through socket.io).

->The server will then find 7 other people to connect the peer to.

->All peers receive information from the server (either a channel or other peer's client information) and set up a video and audio conference.